# How do I delete a folder that gives me this error dialog: Folder Access Denied. You need permission to perform this action

Tags: windows, operating-system, directory

Ok, let me get some things out of the way first.

1. I have OWNERSHIP of the folder via Administrator profile.
2. I have set Permissions for FULL CONTROL  (Allow checked).

I did the 2 things mentioned above after looking on SO for related answers to my question.

BUT, despite having ownership and full control of the folder I still get the error in the question title: Folder Access Denied.  WHAT?!

When I check the subfolders in the folder I want to delete I noticed that I didn't have ownership and full control over all of them.  I tried to individually right click each subfolder and take ownership/full control and then delete them (this works), but there are 1000s of folders...and it's tedious to delete them all manually this way.

I'm familiar with checking off "Replace owner on sub-containers and objects" when in the advance security settings....but doing that still doesn't allow me to delete this darn folder.

HELP!

Comment: what version of windows?

Comment: "Ownership of the folder via Administrator profile" doesn't actually mean anything.  Do you mean that the Administrators group is the owner of the folder?  To which security primitive have you given full control, Administrators or your own account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are any of the folders or subfolders "Read Only?" Whenever I get this error, it is sometimes fixed by opening the folder's properties than checking and unchecking the read only option. It should prompt you if you want to do it to all nested folders, and than apply yes.

Another question I have to help you solve this is if this is a user created folder program created?

**Actually after reading "1000s of folders" it sounds very similar to a common worm virus. I would recommend a full system virus scan along with a scan on this specified folder. Hope this helps. :D**